# Extracting a Sharepoint List including the attachments

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Any clue on how to extract a sharepoint list with all the attachments?

I've seen some powershell articles but i am a complete noob with this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The property you need to use is `SPListItem.Attachments` ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.attachments.aspx))

Since you haven't provided any code to work from I've had to make a simple example. I would suggest posting the code you're working on in future, you will receive much better replies.

```
using (var objSite = new SPSite("http://sharepointsite"))
{
    using (var web = objSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        var objlist = web.Lists["Testing List"];

        var objItem = objlist.GetItemById(1);
        var attachments = objItem.Attachments;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Elvis, where so i execute the above code? In command prompt ?